# Can't invoke celery task in Django tests synchronously

Tags: python, django, celery, django-tests

I'd like to invoke celery tasks synchronously during my Django tests without need to run celery worker. To achieve this I have specified `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` in my settings.py but it doesn't seem to work. So I decided to apply override_settings decorator to specific test that looks like this

```
@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True, BROKER_BACKEND='memory',
                       CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS=True)
def test_foo(self):
...
```

Unfortunately, this test still invokes task in my celery worker. What I can be missing? To be specific, I'm using Django 1.10 with Celery 4.0.0.

Comment: If celery relevant settings are persisted on some in-memory object in the celery app on startup time of your test runner, overriding them might have no effect. Have you tried starting your test runner with a different settings file with the settings you want?

Comment: This seems to be known issue. There is a discussion on the topic (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/1WmrfFZ9nHs). They change the setting at runtime on the `celery.Celery().conf` object, not the the typical `django.conf`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In **celery 4.0** configuration parameters has changed,

Try these instead in your tests,

```
@override_settings(
    task_eager_propagates=True,
    task_always_eager=True,
    broker_url='memory://',
    backend='memory'
)
```

I was facing same issue, solved using new lowercase names for tests as well as in default celery settings.

Here is new settings to original settings map,
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

Celery settings change info:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#lowercase-setting-names